# How to make all number combinations of numbers below a certain numpy array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a certain numpy array of integers and I want to make an array of arrays that contains all combinations of numbers below it. As an example, [2,3] would yield

```
[[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[2,2],[1,3],[3,3]]
```

because that would be all the combinations of arrays with numbers less than or equal to [2,3].

Comment: Why there is `[3,3]` in your array?

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

a,b = 2,3

list(product(np.arange(a)+1,np.arange(b)+1))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: For some reason she also has `[3,3]` in the list

Comment: Is that readily available on spyder? Thank you!

Comment: Spyder is just an IDE, depending on your python. Should be available.

Comment: Great, thanks. You were very helpful!

Comment: Is there a way to make the argument of product an array so I can make it any size? Sorry for the inconvenience.